# Collator doesn't sort right for given Locale

Tags: java, sorting, internationalization, collation

Here's the locale alphabet order: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abeceda)
Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale loc = new Locale("sr","RS");

    Collator col = Collator.getInstance(loc);
    col.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);

    List<String> slova = new ArrayList<String>();

    slova.add("Austrija");
    slova.add("Slovačka");
    slova.add("Č");
    slova.add("Đ");
    slova.add("C");
    slova.add("Grčka");
    slova.add("Slovenija");
    slova.add("Španija");
    slova.add("Švajcarska");
    slova.add("Švedska");
    slova.add("Srbija");

    Collections.sort(slova,col);

    for(String s: slova)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

And here's the output:

Austrija
C
Č
Grčka
Slovačka
Slovenija
Španija
Srbija
Švajcarska
Švedska
Đ

As you can see from the link above this is not the correct ordering.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Words beginning with S and Š are mixed and Đ is not supposed to be at the end.

Comment: Assumption that everyone can see that output is wrong is strong exaggerated.

Comment: That's why I added link with alphabet order at the top and added comment pointing out what's wrong with the output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just found out it's a known issue caused by political and lingual circumstances. Thanks for help.

Comment: I am not so sure about this. Sorting rules are captured by various releases of Unicode Standard (unicode.org). Current standard version (6.0) may have correct sorting rules for Serbia, but Java implements some previous snapshot. Please take a look at ICU's implementation: http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Collator.html and see if it is sorting the right way.

Answer (score 3):

As I found on your [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abeceda) page and @Vash his [ISO](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html) link. I think you mean by "sr" Serbia? Then you will have to choose "cs" as country.

Edit: it depends on the java version you use. Java 6 uses the new [iso](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) standard.

Comment: Vash's link points to outdated iso codes. I've checked supported locales and Collator does support sr_RS as well as legacy sr_CS. Using sr_CS returns the same output.

Comment: ISO-3166 can't be outdated by definition. The link is from Java documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem could be that there is no country in [ISO-3166](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html) with code RS

Comment: http://www.iso.org/iso/english_country_names_and_code_elements and when I call getAvailableLocales() on Collator i get sr_RS among the others.

Answer (score 0):

If the sort order you want is not available, you can create your own order with a 
[RuleBasedCollator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html). Don't be scared by the documentation of this class. It is as easy as:

```
String rules = "< a < b < c < ç < d ...";
RuleBasedCollator myRuleBased = new RuleBasedCollator(rules);
Collections.sort(myList, myRuleBased);
```

Comment: Well it doesn't quite solve my problem as I need to do sort based on a lot of dynamically obtained Locales, which would mean I'd have to define a rule that would encompass over 40 different languages. Even if I was willing to write such monster, it would've be even worse nightmare to maintain it. I've opted to substitute 'sr' with similar Locale.