# Java array sort UTF-8

Tags: java, sorting, utf-8, collation

I want to sort an `ArrayList<String>` but the problem is my native language characters - my alphabet is like this: `a, ą, b, c, č, d, e, f ... z, ž`. As you see `z` character is second from the end and `ą` is second in alphabet, so after I sort my array it is sorted incorrectly. All my native language characters are moved to the end of array. Example:

```
package lt;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("bbc");
        items.add("ąbc");
        items.add("abc");
        items.add("zzz");

        System.out.println("Unsorted: ");
        for(String str : items) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }

        Collections.sort(items);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Sorted: ");
        for(String str : items) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Unsorted: 
bbc
ąbc
abc
zzz

Sorted: 
abc
bbc
zzz
ąbc
```

Should be:

```
Sorted:
abc
ąbc
bbc
zzz
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225523/collator-doesnt-sort-right-for-given-locale)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) class.

For example

```
Locale lithuanian = new Locale("lt_LT");
Collator lithuanianCollator = Collator.getInstance(lithuanian);
```

And then sort the collection using this collator

```
Collections.sort(theList, lithuanianCollator);
```

Comment: My country is Lithuania, and language is Lithuanian, what should I do, because if I am correct my Language is not supported by Locale class?

Comment: This answer is correct, but there's no need to create a Comparator — Collator is already an instance of Comparator.  Collections.sort(myList, Collator.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH)); is complete code.

Comment: `Collator` **is-a** `Comparator` by design. Creating another `Comparator` is unecessary.

Comment: If your language isn't supported by Locale, then you're in trouble. Fortunately, according to this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html  Lithuanian is supported by Locale in java 7. Since there isn't a constant, you'll need to construct an instance of Locale yourself: Locale lithuanian = new Locale("lt_LT");

Comment: @SeanReilly, Elite - thanks, I didn't know it. Minutis - please see Sean's response.

Comment: @SeanReilly thanks, I found it out, but this is what I did, so you're right.

Comment: Why wouldn’t you be using the ICU classes if you’re dealing with Unicode? There at least you can depend on things.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) to do locale sensitive String comparisions.

Comment: Thanks, but the above answer is more improved, thought you are right.